# React Native - Atom won't auto complete css

Tags: css, react-native, autocomplete, atom-editor, nuclide-editor

I've recently started using Atom for react-native. The Atom editor won't auto-complete anything relate to css even though it should be automatically integrated using the auto-complete+.
Regardless, I downloaded additional packages who should have taken care of the job but they didn't.
Just to be more clear:

```
viewStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8',
    alignItems: 'center
}
```

In the above example the editor won't autocomplete nor suggest anything regarding the `alignItems` or `backgroundColor`.

Someone has any idea for why this could occur and can offer any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

React native's styles aren't strictly speaking css so you need a javascript handler which knows react native rather than a css handler.

I use VSCode now so I'm not sure if there's already one out there that does autocomplete for StyleSheet.

If you can't find one that does this already, you would either need to implement your own, offer help to a github project which is developing one for react native by copying and pasting some of the work done in autocomplete+ or ask a project to add this in.

Answer (score 1):

I had kind of the same problem too, Atom was not auto completing anything related to styles in React Native project. So I have googled "atom react native stylesheet autocomplete" and found plugin called "**atom-react-native-style**".

You can install it by entering `apm install atom-react-native-style` in command line.
See more details here:
https://atom.io/packages/atom-react-native-style